# deadlock linux dudas sobre creacion de archivo bloqueado

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux

ya se tiene el programa, pero mi duda es como se crea el archivo bloqueado?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

++[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por cierto... qué es un _archivo bloqueado_? Un archivo que no permite ser modificado?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas algo como `un-archivo`, a diferencia de Windows, no se busca ese archivo en el directorio actual sino en los directorios definidos en el `PATH` (ejecutar `echo $PATH` para ver los directorios configurados en el ambiente). Si lo que quieres hacer es ejecutar `un-archivo`  que está en el directorio actual lo ejecutas así: `./un-archivo` (en caso de ser un archivo ejecutable).... y si lo que quieres es mostrar su contenido en pantalla: `cat un-archivo`

Comment: También en windows se busca en el PATH, no?

Comment: Se que se busca en el directorio actual, aparte del PATH.... creo recordar que primero se verifica el directorio actual.... pero no apostaría x ello. Windows no es mi fuerte (y espero que así siga siendo hasta el final de mis días).

Answer (score 0):

Cuando escribes una palabra en la terminal de Bash, esta sigue un orden de búsqueda para hacerse a la idea de qué comando ejecutar.

Este orden es algo [así](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Search-and-Execution.html#Command-Search-and-Execution):

1. Si el comando no tiene diagonales, entonces busca un alias o keyword, o una función definida en Bash
2. Busca en los builtins
3. Busca los ejecutables en los directorios mostrados en la variable de ambiente `$PATH`
4. Si el comando contiene diagonales, entonces ejecuta el programa llamado
5. Si no funciona nada de lo anterior, asume que el comando en un script the shell

En tu caso, parece ser que quieres ejecutar un ejecutable llamado *ejemplodeadlock*. En ese caso, ejecútalo con su ruta completa (con diagonales) o con un alias de la ruta:

```
$ ./ejemplodeadlock
$ /path/completo/ejemplodeadlock
```

O escribe el programa que debe correr ese archivo y pásale su nombre como parámetro:

```
$ bash ./ejemplodeadlock
$ python ./ejemplodeadlock
```

O cualquier programa que sea tu caso.

También puedes volvero un alias, o parte de una función, o hacerle ejecutable y copiarlo a una carpeta del `$PATH`, o añadir la ruta del directorio de ese ejecutable a la variable `$PATH`.

Pero, si tu duda es sobre crear un simple archivo, puedes realizar:

```
$ touch ./ejemplodeadlock
```